# How to get unsigned attributies from detached signature using BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, cryptography, content-management-system, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I need to get list of unsigned attributies from detached CMS signature **BEFORE** veryfing the signature.

I need to find one special attribute with specific OID

Standard .Net code does not work

```
signedCms.Decode(sig);
signedCms.CheckSignature(true);
```

It fails with an error

> Cannot find the original signer

I think that BouncyCastle library can help but I don't have any experience with it

Comment: Probably the signing certificate wasn't included, so you should supply it to the signature verification function (and no, I don't know the API out of the top of my head, I'm just supplying a solution vector here instead of a full solution).

Comment: Yes, I know. But I need possibility to get OIDs even if signature does not have a certificate included

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get OIDs from signature without verifying it

```
byte[] sig = File.ReadAllBytes(signName);
            ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(File.ReadAllBytes(contentName));

            SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, true);
            signedCms.Decode(sig);
```